# git-svn with git extensions stuck on Authentication realm

Tags: git, git-svn

I'm trying to checkout svn repository through git, in git extensions app, on the input screen I specify an http url for the svn repo, and an authors file that map my svn user to the git user.
I get stuck on "Authentication realm:  Subversion Repository"

What did I miss?

Answer (score 4):

Double check the user name and password, and eventually the repository URL, that you are using. I had Authentication realm:  problem, because IT admin had changed the password of the svn user.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Git Extensions's GUI lacks getting updated SVN credentials. Just run svn rebase from the command line:

Tools -> Git bash

```
$ git svn rebase
```

Here you can enter updated password.

Answer (score 0):

I have been bashing my head for this for a while but found out the reason ,

if you have a secured svn repository you should use

```
$ svn2git http://svn.example.com/path/to/repo --username <<user_with_perms>>
```

yet this doesn't ask you for a password unless you hit "Enter".(and of course it doesn't give you any instructions to do so)

For my case we had a non standard structured repo so i used ;

```
$ svn2git http://svn.example.com/path/to/repo --username <<user_with_perms>> --rootistrunk  -v
```

--verbose or -v does really help btw